# How to activate a generic method that takes an action as its parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics

How would you go about using reflection to execute the following method when the type can only be inferred at runtime?

```
MainObject.TheMethod<T>(Action<OtherObject<T>>)
```

in everyday use, typically:

```
mainObject.Method<Message>(m => m.Do("Something"))
```

So, given a list of types, I need to substitute them for T in the method above and invoke.

This is where I got before my head to turned to putty:

```
var mapped = typeof(Action<OtherObject<>>).MakeGenericType(t.GetType());
Activator.CreateInstance(mapped,  new object[] { erm do something?});

typeof(OtherObject)
    .GetMethod("TheMethod")
    .MakeGenericMethod(t.GetType())
    .Invoke(model, new object[] { new mapped(m => m.Do("Something")) });
```

**Update:** For clarification, i have a list of types and i wish to execute the same known method of OtherObject for each. Pseudo-code:

```
foreach(var t in types)
{
    mainObject.TheMethod<t>(mo => mo.Do("Something"))
}
```

(The type of the parameter for TheMethod() is `Action<OtherObject<T>>` as stated above)

```
FluentNHibernate.Automapping.AutoPersistenceModel Override<T>(System.Action<AutoMapping<T>> populateMap)
```

the action is the same of `AutoMapping<T>.Where("something")`

```
model.Override<Message>(m => m.Where("DeletedById is null"))
```

Now, do that for a bunch of types :)

Comment: Is the body of the action always the same, i.e. always `m.Do("Something")`?

Comment: yes it is, added some clarification above

Comment: checking now, just arrived in the office :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this by using expressions:

```
foreach(var t in types)
{
    var mapped = typeof(AutoMapping<>).MakeGenericType(t);

    var p = Expression.Parameter(mapped, "m");
    var expression = Expression.Lambda(Expression.GetActionType(mapped),
                                       Expression.Call(p, mapped.GetMethod("Do"),
                                       Expression.Constant("Something")), p);

    typeof(SomeOtherObject).GetMethod("TheMethod").MakeGenericMethod(t)
                           .Invoke(model, new object[] { expression.Compile() });
}
```

UPDATE: Complete working example (paste into LINQPad and run it):

```
void Main()
{
    var types = new []{typeof(string), typeof(Guid)};
    SomeOtherObject model = new SomeOtherObject();
    foreach(var t in types)
    {
        var mapped = typeof(AutoMapping<>).MakeGenericType(t);

        var p = Expression.Parameter(mapped, "m");
        var expression = Expression.Lambda(
                             Expression.GetActionType(mapped),
                             Expression.Call(p, mapped.GetMethod("Do"),
                             Expression.Constant("Something")), p);

        typeof(SomeOtherObject).GetMethod("TheMethod")
                               .MakeGenericMethod(t)
                               .Invoke(model,
                                       new object[] { expression.Compile() });
    }
}

class AutoMapping<T>
{
    public void Do(string p)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(p);
    }
}

class SomeOtherObject
{
    public void TheMethod<T>(Action<AutoMapping<T>> action)
    {
        var x = new AutoMapping<T>();
        action(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. Have put this in place. I'm getting type expected on this: var mapped = typeof(Action<AutoMapping<>>).MakeGenericType(t);

Comment: Which .NET version are you using? And can you please give me the complete error message? I assume this is a compilation error?